# Hide Keyboard on Datepicker dialog popup

Tags: android, xamarin, datepicker, android-edittext, keyboard

I have a customdatepickerrender extends to datepickerrender in xamarin android
 [Annoying Keyboard Popup on DatePicker image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPo0x.png)

```
public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer
```

`I have OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)` where i set background to tranparent for the control

whenever date picker is being called it opens up but if i select anything within date picker it shows up keyboard. How do i permanently disable keyboard from this screen? (P.S) I do not have view handle in this render class

Comment: It is not possible to customize the pop up date dialog. As it is wrapped in the framework. You can only create your own DatePickerRenderer to fix that problem.

Comment: Thank you that is what i thought. I did not get any handle on that date poper i have tried all events such as hover, click , tapped but all of them stops working after dialog is shown. I will make a custom date picker.